# How to find a line in file by string and prepend with custom string using PHP?

Tags: php

For example, I have file users.txt with such content:

```
user_10
user_20
user_30
```

I need to find the line which contains string "user_20" and prepend it with the string "disabled".

The resulting file should looks like this:

```
user_10
disabled user_20
user_30
```

File can have approx 200-600 lines.

How can I do it on PHP?

Comment: approximately how many lines are in the file?

Comment: Here's one way: https://eval.in/461807

Comment: @BradKent file can have approx 200-600 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

200-600 lines are very few. If you just need to edit once, try that :

```
    $fr = fopen("users.txt",'r+');
    $content = "";

    while(!feof($fr)) {
        $user = fgets($fr);
        if($user == "user_20") {
          $user = "disabled ".$user;
        }
        $content.= $user;
        $content.= "\r\n";
    }

    file_put_contents("users.txt", $content);
    fclose($fr);
```

Comment: IMHO this line not needed because $user variable already contains linebreak: $content.= "\r\n";

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```
file_put_contents($filename, str_replace('user_20',
                                         'disabled user_20',
                                         file_get_contents($filename)));
```